# How to simply generate bitmaps for every character in the alphabet for a given font?

Tags: fonts, bmp

I want to generate a .bmp file with every character in a specific font.

There used to be a program in the internet called `Font 2 BMP` but somehow it is now nowhere to be found.

It was a perfect solution for me because it printed the .bmps with the character's ASCII code.

Can someone suggest a solution for this ? For instance how to do it in C++ (or C#) as I need this for my project in C++ and this would be really easy for me to implement. Or suggest alternative to `Font 2 BMP`.

Comment: Note that there isn't necessarily a one-to-one relationship between ASCII codes and glyphs (e.g, drawable characters) in newer fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear if you're looking for a tool to solve this problem, or the code to solve it.

Here's a tool that might work for you:
http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/

I don't know what platform you're on, but many platforms (e.g. .NET, Cocoa) allow you to create a Rendering Context, draw a letter onto it, then save that context as a bitmap/png file.

Comment: This is more or less what I want but this tool does not allow for generation of .bmps (one can only export the selected chars to .fnt file).